# Sticky Footer in OSclass

Tags: html, css

I'm using OSclass for my website and I tried to set sticky footer on the bottom, but nothing worked.
You can see my website [here](http://www.khmer-land.com)

It works on my main page because my content is long, but it doesn't work on item or account for example.

**CSS**:

```
body {  
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
font-size: 100%;
background: transparent;
list-style-type:none;
}

.header {
height: auto; 
background-color: #0080c4; 
clear: both;
}

.header_wrap {
width:960px; 
margin:0 auto; 
position:relative; 
padding: 10px 0 160px 0;
}

.header .wcont {
float:left; 
width:468px; 
padding:0px; 
color:#FFFFFF;
}

.content {
clear: both;
margin-bottom: 20px;
width: 960px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.footer {
padding-top: 5px;
padding-right: 33px;
padding-left: 33px;
padding-bottom: 0;
background-color: #0080c4;
clear: both;
position: relative;
}

.footer_wrap {
width:960px; 
margin:0 auto; 
position:relative; 
padding:0 0 25px 0;
}

.footer .wcont {
float:left; 
width:200px; 
padding:0 15px; 
color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Anyone have any idea for resolving it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these properties to your footer, it should fix it:

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works great !

For information, how to let the footer on bottom without sticky style ? I try it too but no way :(

I will choose after which one will better with sticky or not.

Thanks a lot friends !

PS : Sorry for my english, i'm french ^^

Comment: I don't think it's possible to fix the footer on the bottom without CSS, maybe with some Javascript but it would be overcomplicated.

Je ne connais pas de moyen plus simple que le CSS pour résumer :)

Comment: I want to do it with CSS but not fixed. I just want to see it when i scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

`Position: fixed;` and `bottom: 0;` in the footer class styling might give the result you want.